Convert a Unix Value to a Date using looker studio
i really need help on this. I tried all the formulas i could i couldn't find a solution.
I need to use looker studio to convert values like this one: 1699562040000 to a date format. I already converted it using https://www.epochconverter.com/ and it converted to Thursday, 9 November 2023 20:34:00 and this date is correct.
Those values comes from a hubspot report, and i'd like to use looker studio to convert it to a date.
Since timestamp formula doesn't work anymore, i couldn't find a solution for it using calculated fields?
Thank you!
I tried Several formulas using timestamp, cast, parse-datetime like: PARSE_DATETIME("%s", CAST(your_field_name AS STRING)), // Assuming your field name is 'ms_since_epoch'
FORMAT_DATETIME(
DIVIDE(ms_since_epoch, 1000),  // Divide by 1000 for seconds
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  // Adjust format string for desired output
"GMT"                 // Specify desired time zone
), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(your_field AS FLOAT64) / 1000)  , just can't think of anything else.
